# how to run init sql after I create a new postgre instance in terraform

Tags: terraform, rds, sqlclient

I am fine to [create a new rds (postgre) instance with terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html). But I need to run a sql (`init.sql`) after the instance is ready.

This sql need be run once only, what should I do?

I tried `local-exec`, or `remote-exec`, i can't. RDS is created in private subnet (data layer) in VPC, and it is aws managed service. There is no way to login to run sql cli.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Do you need to create a schema/roles on the instances? Or do you have a specific SQL script you would like to run on creation?

Comment: similar, such as create the databases, tables with init data.

Comment: There is no way to do this currently, I believe. The ideal way to do it would be to do it from your application server (or something similar). Some options, out of many
1. If you are using Terraform to deploy your application server and assuming it's EC2, you could first create the RDS instance/s and then create your application server and using remote-exec to run your init.sql script.
2. If you use any CI pipeline to deploy your code, you can add initializing your DB as another step.
3. You could also add in logic to your application to initialize your DB during the first start.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same request. I end with the solution to [set a schedule task in ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html). Set the schedule time to passed date, it will not run, until I manually active it with current time.

So after the database is created by terraform, I login aws console to active this schedule task to run one time only

It will be useful in the future, if new schema need be applied.

I also adjust the psql client docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/jbergknoff/postgresql-client/) and add aws cli in it, so I can copy the sql from s3 and run the updates.